# Implementing Collatz Function

Tags: haskell

[Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#curried-functions) mentions the Collatz Sequences:

> We take a natural number. If that number is even, we divide it by two.
>   If it's odd, we multiply it by 3 and then add 1 to that.

When I tried to implement it, I ran into a problem

```
collatz :: (Integral a) => a -> [a]
collatz x 
 | odd x    = f x : collatz (f x)
 | otherwise = g x : collatz (g x)
     where f y = y*3 + 1
           g y = y/2
```

But I get this compile-time error:

```
CollatzSeq.hs:10:16:
Could not deduce (Fractional a) arising from a use of `g'
from the context (Integral a)
  bound by the type signature for collatz :: Integral a => a -> [a]
  at CollatzSeq.hs:7:12-35
Possible fix:
  add (Fractional a) to the context of
    the type signature for collatz :: Integral a => a -> [a]
In the first argument of `(:)', namely `g x'
In the expression: g x : collatz (g x)
In an equation for `collatz':
    collatz x
      | odd' x = f x : collatz (f x)
      | otherwise = g x : collatz (g x)
      where
          f y = y * 3 + 1
          g y = y / 2
```

As I understand, the problem is that calling `collatz (g x)` can return a `Fractional` since `y / 2` returns a `Double`:

```
Prelude> let x = 4 / 2
Prelude> :t x
x :: Double
```

I tried to fix this type error by adding `floor` in front of the `y/2`, but that didn't work.

Please tell me how to fix this error.

Comment: it seems to me the more consistent definition is to add `x` to the head, not `f x` or `g x`: `collatz 1 = [1]; collatz x | odd x = x : collatz (x * 3 +1); collatz x = x : collatz (div x 2)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `div` instead of `(/)`. Alternately, if you want another rounding strategy than `floor`, you may use `fromIntegral`, as in

```
round (fromIntegral y / 2)
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that "round" is implemented as "round to even" aka "banker's rounding".  This is very surprising to most people who went through public school in the US.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson can you elaborate? `round 0.6 = 1`

Comment: @SassaNF: It means that when you've got a number equally close to two integers, you choose the even one, e.g. `round 1.5 = round 2.5 = 2`. See: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even)

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the way `/` is defined. GHCI shows this result for `:t (/)`:

```
(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
```

An alternative would be to use `div`, which has the type signature:

```
div :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
```

Secondly, you are skipping the input term in your current implementation. That should not be the case.

Finally, you need to add the base case for input = 1, otherwise your function will get caught in an infinite loop. You may change it to:

```
collatz :: (Integral a) => a -> [a]
collatz 1 = [1]
collatz x 
 | odd x    = x : collatz (f x)
 | otherwise = x : collatz (g x)
 where f y = y*3 + 1
       g y = y `div` 2
```